# Copy files remotely with LINUX

Tags: ssh

I know I can use something like 
SCP...

But, I am logged into the computer from my own computer using ssh.

When I try to copy to `/home/`
it just copies it to the home directory of the remote computer. How do I copy it to the home directory of my local computer?

Comment: well, what if you enter your home comp as dest and the comp you're logged in as , as src https://varrunr.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/scp-copy-fromto-remote-server-with-ssh/

Answer (score 0):

You can use scp as long as both computers support it.  scp can be used in this format:

To copy a file from local computer to remote computer:

```
scp /home/file.txt username@remote_computer_address:/home/file.txt
```

The remote_computer_address could be a domain name or IP address

The opposite also works

```
scp username@remote_computer_address:/home/file.txt /home/file.txt
```

Copy an entire directory

```
scp -r /home username@remote_computer_address:/home
```

Again the opposite direction

```
scp -r username@remote_computer_address:/home /home
```